# Serverless command "project" not found

Tags: serverless-framework

I want to create a large project (**not a simple template**) with serverless framework.

The template should be created by running the command line :

```
serverless project create
```

but i receive the error

```
Serverless command "project" not found
```

Here the docs of this command line:

```
https://serverless.readme.io/docs/configuring-aws
https://serverless.readme.io/docs/project-create
```

Do you have any idea about this issue ??

My serverless version is 1.31.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new service, use the following command:

```
# Create a new Serverless Service/Project
$ serverless create --template aws-nodejs --path my-service
# Change into the newly created directory
$ cd my-service
```

---

Your docs are for Serverless 0.5.
You'll find the correct docs at: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/

You can also have a list of available commands with:

```
$ serverless --help
```

And a list of available templates with:

```
$ serverless create --help
```

---

If your project has a lot of resources, you will need to split it in multiple services or use nested stacks. [You will find some solutions here.](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-workaround-cloudformation-200-resource-limit/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but creating a simple template will be very complicated for a large project, for example ,  i already have  500 functions  (Nodejs Project), so if I want to update my functions (ex: database configuration ..) I can't run deploy for each function !!

Comment: When you use `deploy` it deploys your whole service, not just one function. And in a service you can have just one function as well as 1000 functions and 300 databases configurations.

Comment: Actually, in a service you can have up to 200 resources (and not >1000 as my previous comment suggest). If you have more than 200 resources, you'll need to create multiple services.

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to solutions for splitting your project into multiple services.